# How to identify I already own a paid app which is on a 100% discount offer period?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

Google Play Store recently got updated in my device to v11.8.xx. I'm used to buying paid apps gone free (PAGF) [free for a limited time]. In v11.7.xx or earlier, if I bought a PAGF, the view used to change from image 1 to image 2, as shown below. In v11.7.xx, even if the offer period was over, or a new offer period emerged I would always used to get Image 2, which visually confirmed me that I already owned the app, and I needed not to install it.

[image: IMG: 1]
[image: IMG: 2]

However, in v11.8.xx, whether I had earlier bought the app or not, as long as there is an offer running on the app, I get the following image. The striked-down text below the Install button confuses me, because visually I can't get to know whether I already own this app or not.

[image: IMG: 3]

Why is this a problem? Can I not just tap on that button and get along with it? Well, once in a while, yeah, I can do it. But. I'm habitual of going on a PAGF installation spree everyday (I use PAGF app and App Sales app to find such apps), and every extra click bothers me. It's more than the click. It is the confusion surrounding it.

How do I fix this?

I thought of going back to v11.7.xx but Play Store automatically updates me to latest version. I also tried setting immutable bit onto its APK (v11.7.xx) but it didn't work for me. I know, I can go to Account → Order History, but finding an app out of 100s of owned paid app is not efficient and is quite irritating too.

I'm using a stock and rooted Android 7.1.1 on a Nexus 6 with Xposed Framework.

Comment: In the PlayStore web site you can see a small green check mark on owned apps if you are on the page where multiple apps are displayed (e.g. as a result of a search engine). The PlayStore web site has an API that retrieves a list of all apps you own and then displays this check mark.

Comment: @Robert. Consider this case. I bought an app on 100% discount which is visible in my order history [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzNKs.png). But when I use Play Store's search engine to find apps with similar name, the app does show up but that check mark of purchased is not listed against it. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAhzk.png). I'm not sure why though. Is it because the app is still in offer period or is it a  caching issue? But the argument remains. It is confusing.

Comment: The screenshots are from the app. Try the PlayStore web site in a webbrowser instead  - preferred in desktop mode.

Comment: Yes, it works on the website.

Comment: @Firelord looks like caching issue. Saw that for one app (not marked purchased), cleaned cache, restarted and it shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't paid attention to this aspect in previous versions of Play Store but with the current version I see no confusion

**If you don't see offer period (as in your first screenshot) you can install** or *you own the app* as you say

- Discount offer not availed

[image]

- Discount offer availed app installed and uninstalled

[image]

The **strike through** pricing is only shown for the duration of offer. See

- [About sale price annotations](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/9017019?hl=en)
- [Earn more revenue with the right monetization options](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/monetization-options)

Here's an app that I bought on sale many months ago and it seems to have an indefinite offer period and it shows discounted price

[image]

Bottom line - ignore the strike through pricing. You are good as long as you don't see the offer duration notice